# how to find type in list of types, by lets say an id, like db queries, getPostById PostId

Tags: haskell

lets say i have those functions and types:

```
type PostId = Int
type PostTitle = String

data Post = Post PostId PostTitle deriving (Show,Eq)

posts = [Post 1 "serjo",Post 2 "agro"]

findPostById :: PostId -> [Post] -> Maybe Post
findPostById post posts
  | (PostId id) `elem` posts = Just post
  | otherwise = Nothing

findIdInList :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
findIdInList whatNumber listOfNums
  | whatNumber `elem` listOfNums = Just whatNumber
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

what iam trying to achieve is:
main = print (findPostById (PostId 1) posts)

i already made a function by findPostByPost with post constructor and list
but i want like db operation to find by id

Comment: What do you think ``(PostId id) `elem` posts`` does?

Comment: making a new postid with id and checks in posts list

Comment: i can filter the list by post id with comparison and then do check if list is empty
but i want to find a better way

Comment: ``x `elem` y`` checks whether `x` is an element of list `y`. For that to work, `x` must have the same type as the elements of list `y`, but that's not your case. You can instead use the library function `find` with a proper predicate argument. Alternatively, use `filter` or a list comprehension to restrict your list to those elements having the right ID; after, check if such restricted list is empty.

Comment: thank you, i already used this method, just was wondering if there is a better way